# Ever since phrase

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is correct?

1. This is the first time I have applied the brakes ever since I am driving.
2. This is the first time I have applied the brakes ever since I am driving from home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is grammatical in standard English, because *since* cannot be followed by a present progressive.

*Since* normally has to be followed by an expression which disgnates a point in time, not a period, such as "since last Wednesday", or "since I started driving". But (for reasons which are not clear to me) it can be followed by a perfect, eg "since I have been driving", or "since I have been in the car".

Also the placement of "ever", though not ungrammatical, is confusing and unidiomatic. It is confusing because there is an idiom "ever since", which means "at all times since", and does not fit here; and (at least in reading) that is what the sentence looks as if it is using. But in any case, before the verb is more common, so

> This is the first time I have ever applied the brakes since I started driving from home

is possible, but I think people are far more likely to say

> This is the first time I have applied the brakes since I left home.

Note that I dropped "ever" here, because it seems unnecessarily emphatic. But you could put it in.

Comment: "Since" can be followed by a a description of an event which covers a period, but I suppose it implies "the end of"  "The army has shrunk since World War two."

Comment: Can I say like this? 'Ever since I left home this is the first time I have applied the brakes'. Ever since - at all times can also be interpreted as process started at particular time in past(which is leaving home here) till now. Please explain

Comment: _Ever since_ means doing something _all the time_ beginning from that moment while _the first time_ is just _once_. A classic example of usage from rock opera  Tommy: _**Ever since** I was a young boy **I've played** the silver ball_.*

Comment: Ever since I left home (process of leaving home at some point in time till now the present moment) this is the first time I have applied the brakes. Is this correct one?

Comment: No. As Alex_ander said, _ever since_ designates something continuous over the whole period. It is inconsistent with the punctual _the first time_.